# É uma boa idéia colocar o código no Pastebin ao invés de colocar o código na pergunta?

Tags: debate

Estava dando uma lida nessa pergunta [Como exibir tabela mesmo sem ter resultado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82191/como-exibir-tabela-mesmo-sem-ter-resultado) e me deparei com um código que foi colocado no Pastebin.

Isso seria uma boa idéia, já que temos snnipets e/ou formas específicas para tratar código?

Comment: Não, primeiro pq o código não deve ser gigante ou seja o erro já deve estar isolado  e só a porção de código referente a ele deve ir para a pergunta, segundo nem todo mundo tem paciência de ler um código gigante fora da pergunta, o pastebin/ideone etc são apenas apoio se o link sumir vai invalidar a perguta(caso não tenha o código no corpo), e algumas vezes esses sites podem ser bloqueados o que já diminui a chance da pergunta obter uma resposta.

Comment: @rray responde, tá boa.

Comment: @rray  não lembro como eu marco alguém em uma resposta, mas te dei os devidos créditos na minha.

Comment: @OlimonF. valeu :D

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4204/3635

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Não

O Stack Overflow **confia em si mesmo** para manter as perguntas e respostas intactas por um grande período de tempo. Caso um serviço popular de desenvolvedores *(Pastebin, SQL Fiddle)* tornar o link inválido, a pergunta/resposta também perderá substancialmente seu valor. E por esse motivo, o código **sempre** deve estar no corpo da pergunta/resposta.

---

#### Outros Argumentos

- Se seu código é grande e **precisa** ser postado em um site de terceiros, provavelmente é um sinal de que ele é muito complexo ou você não isolou o problema e casos assim não são de muita utilidade para a comunidade em geral, pois muitas vezes esses problemas são especificos.
- Muitas empresas tem algum *firewall* e podem bloquear esses links para serviços externos.
- Códigos grandes resultam em desânimo e perda de paciência. As chances de uma resposta para códigos  grandes podem diminuir drasticamente.
- O link externo pode tornar-se inválido e a pergunta/resposta perderá grande parte do seu valor.

#### Contudo, nem sempre o código precisa estar na pergunta/resposta

Se o conteúdo do código for opcional, então não há problema algum em adicionar ele através de um serviço externo. Várias ferramentas são realmente excelentes para demonstrar uma idéia, provar algo ou dar um exemplo funcional; ainda tem aquelas ferramentas estilo *Pastebin*, que são muito boas para postar arquivos de *logs*.

<sup><sub>Créditos ao @rray e outros contribuidores.</sub></sup>

Comment: Muito bom. Meu único corolário seria que o pastbin (ou stack snippet), etc servem como um adendo à pergunta, que pode dar uma demonstração prática do problema, ou fornecer mais contexto ao trecho menor de código que foi inserido na pergunta. Ele nunca deve ser a base.

Comment: Não sei se *adendo*... muita pergunta tem código demais e texto de menos e vice versa. Poucas num campo e noutro são boas de verdade. Tirando o que é teoria e técnicas avançadas, acho que a base do dia a dia é um mix de texto e código.

Comment: Muito código e nenhuma descrição do problema só atrai downvotes.